# Use random value in range to change value in dataset

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset that is full of NaN and outliner values.

I have managed to locate and replace this values by random number from certain range using:

```
dataset.loc[(dataset['MaxHR'] == 1000) & (dataset['Age'] < 50), 'MaxHR'] = random.randrange(138, 176)
```

My problem is that I meant that `random.randrange(138, 176)` pick one number for each time that number 1000 occur.

My code just picks a number and for every row and column that meet conditions assert one number for the whole column.

Comment: What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: Perhaps it would make sense to generate a [random number for each row in your dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054497/random-value-for-each-row-in-pandas-data-frame) and then swap out the matching rows (1000 & age<50) with the generated random number in that same row.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider to use the `applymap` method. Here a simple example :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]], columns=['a', 'b'])
def clean(x):
    if x == 1:
        return random.randrange(138, 176)
    else:
        return x

df = df.applymap(lambda x: clean(x))
```